# How can i increase the round corner button width dynamically depends on the text size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can i increase the round corner button width dynamically depends on the text size in CSS ?

i have 10 round corner buttons with different text size base, i want the solution is buttons size should increase dynamically based on text size....

Is any solution for this using HTML and CSS, or any other way to solve using scripting language.

Help..,

Comment: can you create a fiddle so we could help you better?

Comment: what is "the round corner button"?

Comment: something like jsfiddle.net/2dGR4/ ?

Comment: all, please click the below link,                                              http://jsfiddle.net/Sm8tK/32/..............   i want the solution for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XAU8V/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button small">Small</a>
    <a href="#" class="button medium">Medium</a>
    <a href="#" class="button large">Large</a>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.button {
   border: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #65a9d7;
   padding: 5px 30px;
   color: white;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
   -moz-border-radius: 1em;
   border-radius: 1em;
}

.small {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.medium {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.large {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The border radius is in "em", so it is in relation to the parent value (even though it's not really a parent in this example). Em's can get a little tricky due to inheritance.

Comment: thanks alot, still i have one doubt,  border-radius: 1em; In this what is the use of 'em'..,